# Comparing Saved TXT and EditText text

Tags: android, file

I Want to Make A System that compares password (4 letter numeric).

Input Code (I Already Have fis)

```
fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String text;

        while((text = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(text).append("\n");
        }

        String finalinput = sb.toString();

        String finalpassinput = password.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(this, "finalinput:"+finalinput+"finalpassinput:"+finalpassinput,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(finalinput.equals(finalpassinput))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Login!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Incorrect Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

And This Source Code will keep say that the two passwords are different.
How I Wrote My File :

```
fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME_PW, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(encodedpw.getBytes());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to " + getFilesDir() + "/" + FILE_NAME_PW, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I am curious if encodepw.getBytes() will change anything to the string (Including null characters, etc.) and if Java won't think them the same.
Thank you.

Comment: nvm. I Found It. finalinput is "1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the answer to it. The finalinput variable had some null charachter before it, so you can get pure string using this function.

```
public static String FileStringParse(String FileString)
{
    FileString = FileString.replaceAll("\\D+","");
    return FileString;
}
```